# VBA code to find running userform caption of other Excel macro file

Tags: excel, vba

We have a third party addin in Excel. The addin is like Wizard. I need to capture the caption of each running userform into another excel file.
I can't access to the third party Addin code to print the userform caption.

Please let me know if any other option to get the current running userform names.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim frm As Object

    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.Visible Then MsgBox frm.Caption
    Next frm

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi , Thank for your immediate response. When I run the above code excel not allowing to click the add-in in the ribbon.

Comment: You'll probably want to output the `frm.Caption` to a cell instead of a msgbox then.

Comment: Yes,  once I click on the add-in,  a user form will appears in the screen , that user form caption should print in another excel workbook(eg:test.xlsx). After giving next in the wizard another user form will appears. So I need to capture each user form name into another excel (test.xlsx)workbook.

Comment: You'll need to run the provided code while a userform is open, it won't capture it automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to run two macros at same time ? In one excel workbook I can run the add-in and another excel macro will capture the user form caption and print.

Comment: If the other workbook is a separate instance of Excel, it probably won't see forms in your original workbook.  And typically in order to separately run VBA code while a userform is open, the userform needs to be opened as modeless `UserForm.Show vbModeless`.  Of course, if you can't access the add-in's VBA code, you can't change how the userform is loaded.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your immediate response to my query.